# Draw Circle by getting Input from Textfield in OpenLayer2

Tags: openlayers

I want to draw a circle on a map. Can anyone help in drawing circle on map by taking values from user in Openlayer2 ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have done with it.  If anyone found it in future. kindly check this lick. cheers :)      http://jsfiddle.net/zLjae81b/30/